# If you set a field name as an Alias, can you utilize that name within SQL code?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a beginner in using SQL and I'm just messing around to learn. If I was trying to combine a First Name field and a Last Name field into a Name field, can I use that alias in my SQL code?

For example, (using the Northwind Access sample DB) I was trying to pull the Company and Address of all the Names that start with "J" using an alias for the name field

Example code below

```
SELECT Company, Address, [First Name] + " " + [Last Name] AS Name
FROM Customers
WHERE Name LIKE "J%";
```

In Access this is popping up a parameter box and not returning results even though I know there are names that start with J.

Comment: depends on the DB. access' sql parser is extremely anal and won't allow it. Other DB's will in some (not all) circumstances. You'd have to write out the whole expression again for access: `where [firstname] + " " + [lastname] LIKE ...`, or using a `having` clause instead.

Comment: I tried re-writing it like `WHERE ([First name] + " " + [Last Name]) LIKE "J%";` and that still didn't return the right info.

Comment: Is the last name NULL?

Comment: No. There's always a value in [First Name]

Comment: @arooney88 sorry, I meant last name

Comment: @SpectralGhost [Last Name] field also always has a value.

Comment: @arooney88 change " " to ' '

Comment: You're concatenating the columns incorrectly. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/concatenate.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953822/ms-access-select-as-order-by-error) you can only output alias names in Access. Can't use them as part of your query. Didn't catch who posted this link earlier for credit.

Answer (score 2):

With few exceptions, you cannot use an alias defined in the `SELECT` elsewhere in the query at the same level.  So, you cannot use the alias again in the `SELECT` or `WHERE`, for instance.

But you *can* use a subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT Company, Address, [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] AS Name
      FROM Customers
     ) as c
WHERE Name LIKE "J*";
```

Notice that I changed the string concatenation operator from `+` to `&` and the wildcard in the `LIKE` pattern from '%' to '*'.  These changes are to make the query compatible with MS Access.

Comment: I just realized my mistake using the % instead of * for Access. Thanks for posting!