# Is it possible to use alias in ORDER BY?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query

```
SELECT username, count(username) as number
FROM table
GROUP BY username;
```

and I want to add

```
ORDER BY number DESC
```

to it, but it doesn't work in Access and it thinks that "number" is a parameter.
I know that I can use

```
ORDER BY count(username) DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

but is it possible to use column alias in `ORDER BY` in MS Access?

Comment: Note that this isn't an issue in other RDBMS, and seems to be an issue only in MS-Access.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953822/ms-access-select-as-order-by-error). So no you cannot use an alias in that part of the query.

Comment: I should tell you that link-only answers are not that great as they're candidates to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), even if in this case the accepted answer is not really more complete than yours...