# Alias not recognized in ORDER

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I have a calculated field with an alias field name "Status".  The field shows all correct data.  When I add this alias to the ORDER BY clause the alias is not recognized.

```
SELECT ORG, PR, NOUN, Elapsed, Target_Days, Supportable_Date,
      (Target_Days - Elapsed) AS Status
FROM qry_Gate_Status
ORDER BY ORG, Supportable_Date, Status;
```

How do I get the alias "Status" to work with ORDER BY?

Comment: seems that in ms access this is not possible  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953822/ms-access-select-as-order-by-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-Access -> SELECT AS + ORDER BY = error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953822/ms-access-select-as-order-by-error)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  It helped me to dig up a suitable solution... I'll post an answer to the question.  Thanks @scaisEdge

Comment: the simplest solution is a subquery  ..  @Magicman200777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately aliases are not recognized in Access SQL.  I used the ORDER BY (column number) which is elegant enough for me.

```
SELECT ORG, PR, NOUN, Elapsed, Target_Days, Supportable_Date,
      (Target_Days - Elapsed) AS Status
FROM qry_Gate_Status
ORDER BY ORG, Supportable_Date, 7;
```

Answer (score 3):

Alias cannot be used with `ORDER BY`. Instead, do this:

```
SELECT ORG, PR, NOUN, Elapsed, Target_Days, Supportable_Date,
  (Target_Days - Elapsed) AS Status
FROM qry_Gate_Status
ORDER BY ORG, Supportable_Date, (Target_Days - Elapsed);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that as well but settled with the column number instead.  Great advice nevertheless!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want repeat  code a simple solution could be based on  a subquery

```
select * from (
  SELECT ORG, PR, NOUN, Elapsed, Target_Days, Supportable_Date,
  (Target_Days - Elapsed) AS Status
  FROM qry_Gate_Status
) t
ORDER BY ORG, Supportable_Date, Status;
```