# SQL Query not working using alias, but does work with indexing

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, select, sql-order-by

```
SELECT        Product_ID, Product_Name, Purchase_Cost, Quantity_On_Hand, Purchase_Cost*Quantity_On_Hand AS Total_Item_Value
FROM            PRODUCT
ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

The above code works, but the below doesnt and returns this error.

```
SELECT        Product_ID, Product_Name, Purchase_Cost, Quantity_On_Hand, Purchase_Cost*Quantity_On_Hand AS Total_Item_Value
FROM            PRODUCT
ORDER BY Total_Item_Value DESC
```

Error:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS-Access -> SELECT AS + ORDER BY = error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953822/ms-access-select-as-order-by-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access basically does not allow reusing aliases anywhere in the query. You can either use the column number (as you did), repeat the expression, or use a subquery:

```
SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, Purchase_Cost, Quantity_On_Hand, Purchase_Cost * Quantity_On_Hand AS Total_Item_Value
FROM   PRODUCT
ORDER BY Purchase_Cost * Quantity_On_Hand DESC
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name, Purchase_Cost, Quantity_On_Hand, Purchase_Cost * Quantity_On_Hand AS Total_Item_Value
    FROM   PRODUCT
) x
ORDER BY Total_Item_Value DESC
```